# How to stop Ctrl+Left/Right Arrow from erasing symbols in vi mode in zsh?

Tags: zsh

When using vi mode in zsh, using ctrl+arrows (left or right) in attempt to navigate by words (a force of habit) results in symbols and whole words being erased. How to configure vi mode to prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initially only found about `bindkey -a`, but it didn't work in insert mode. I stumbled upon [zsh advanced binding documentation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Guide/zshguide04.html).

To map a key in insert mode, one must use `bindkey -M viins`. To map a key in the command mode, on can use `bindkey -M vicmd` OR `bindkey -a`. As the documentation states, the latter isn't very readable. The rest is easy, the key for Ctrl+Left Arrow is `'^[[1;5D'`, for Ctrl+Right Arrow is `'^[[1;5C'`, and good mappings are `emacs-backward-word` and `emacs-forward-word` respectively. Resulting configuration is:

```
# vi mode
bindkey -v

bindkey -M vicmd '^[[1;5C' emacs-forward-word
bindkey -M vicmd '^[[1;5D' emacs-backward-word
bindkey -M viins '^[[1;5C' emacs-forward-word
bindkey -M viins '^[[1;5D' emacs-backward-word
```

Comment: Or read the doc like `info zsh keymaps`